# Allow a Folder to be Downloaded on a Website by a Web Browser

Tags: ftp, download, web

So I manage our company website the best I can. What I need to do, is allow a folder and all of its contents to be downloaded by a user. I need it to be downloadable in a similar fashion as when you say download a zip file. By entering the web address and being prompted for a download by your browser.

Now I don't want to zip it up or upload it to an FTP for download. I really want to do what I am asking, allow a folder for download in a similar fashion as you would copy and paste a local folder on your computer.

I'm aware what I am asking may be impossible, but I really hope that it isn't.

The web server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 using IIS 6.

Comment: why don't you want to zip it? And, BTW, for any answer to be useful, you're going to need to include a lot more information, such as the webserver you're using

Comment: I can zip it for sure, but I'd like to find a different solution. And thanks for the heads up about more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip is definitely going to be the easiest solution, unless you're using something like SharePoint, which may have an option to d/l whole folders. The `http` protocol is file-based, so while it would be possible to set up some sort of server rule to send one file after another after clicking on a single link, they'll just end up where the user saves them (typically their Desktop or Downloads folder) and not in a specific folder of their own. If you want to get really fancy, and all your users are running Internet Explorer, you could probably write custom controls to do this for you, but in the end it's going to be a ton of work.

Darth Android's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/610055/137557) will work if you're on a local network with access to a shared drive, but if you're operating over the external net then ZIP is really the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you'll get to this is to expose the folder on a read-only network share, and give the users a UNC url that they can plug into Windows Explorer, such as `\\server\share\path\to\folder`

This will open the folder over the network, and allow them to copy files locally.